# When running an execute on a databae I get the error ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am following this documentation to access my sqlite database. https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Using flask I login to my site by typing in my username and password. This takes me to this route:

```
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    db = get_db_connection()
    cur = db.cursor()
    print(session['userID']) # prints: 1
    print(type(session['userID'])) # prints: <class 'int'>

    query = """SELECT users.firstName, workouts.dateandtime, workouts.id, sets.*, exercises.name FROM users
  JOIN workouts ON users.id = workouts.userID JOIN sets ON workouts.id = sets.workoutID JOIN exercises ON
  sets.exerciseID = exercises.id WHERE users.id = ?"""
   posts_unsorted = cur.execute(query, session['userID']).fetchall()
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

I have looked at my database to make sure the id for the user is an `<int>` and it is. If I type a `1` in place of the `?` in my query the execute works but I need ot be able to look up other users.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The second argument to `cur.execute()` must be a sequence of parameters, not a single parameter. Put `session['userID']` in a list or tuple.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't have to do that when I was using the Havard cs50 course.

Comment: I'm sure you did, you just didn't realize you were doing it.

Comment: Or maybe you were using string formatting instead of cursor parameters.

Comment: Yeah. Taking the training wheels off has led me to a lot of errors that I have had to figure out.